# How to avoid device rotation after external app run?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an issue with the device rotation. I run an app in landscape mode, developed in xamarin, that calls the camera device, takes a photo and returns to the app again and shows its own photogallery.

The problem is the device always returns in portrait after the camera app. If I try to block the app in landscape mode it crashes after the camera because this annoying rotation, even though the picture has saved in the correct storage.

I have created a mask to hide this ugly effect, but even so it's visible for an instant. The app runs perfect without problems, except for that.

The device is a Xiaomi MiA2 Lite. I think here is the problem, but I must develope the app for it.

I've search in the forum and can't find any solution, but now I know that Android's default mode is portrait, maybe it's a start point.

Is there any solution or idea to solve this? I'll appreciate any help.

Thank you!

**EDITED**

I have try OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) with all ConfigChanges without result.

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        switch (newConfig.Orientation)
        {
            case Orientation.Landscape:
                switch (Device.Idiom)
                {
                    case TargetIdiom.Phone:
                        LockRotation(Orientation.Landscape);
                        break;
                    case TargetIdiom.Tablet:
                        LockRotation(Orientation.Landscape);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Orientation.Portrait:
                switch (Device.Idiom)
                {
                    case TargetIdiom.Phone:
                        LockRotation(Orientation.Landscape);
                        break;
                    case TargetIdiom.Tablet:
                        LockRotation(Orientation.Landscape);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess your device is a Xiaomi, not a Xamarin.. Is your app a native android app or a Xamarin app?

Comment: Yes, you're right, Xiaomi. It's a Xamarin app.

Answer (score 0):

All was an issue produced by the system camera. its layout is design to function in portrait mode. Changing the app camera solves this error.